# How do I find and replace HTML entities with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've constructed a calendar template for a Drupal site using an HTML table, and I've got jQuery to add a class 'no-text' to each empty cell:

```
$('table.calendar td:empty').addClass('no-text');
```

This works well, but my problem is that the CMS WYSIWYG editor automatically adds the HTML entity `&nbsp;` to empty cells. I've therefore attempted to find and replace the entities with a 'real' space beforehand, but jQuery fails to find them:

```
$('table.calendar td').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var t = $this.text();
   $this.text(t.replace('[entity here]',''));
});
```

This snippet works fine when replacing a normal string, but the `&nbsp;` seems to be something different!

So my question is this: how can jQuery be used to search and replace HTML entities?

Comment: voting up, as it's a good question. nicely asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be

```
$this.text(t.replace('\u00a0',''));
```

Where `\u00a0` is the unicode character for `&nbsp;`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, folks. This one worked just fine - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
replace(/& nbsp;/g, '');
```

w/o the space after the ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried .html() ?

$this.html('');

Answer (score 1):

This is another alternative that works.

```
var nbsp = unescape("%a0");     // a0 is hex code point for &nbsp;
$this.text(t.replace(nbsp,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your nbsp is within a  tag, rather than an external js file, the html needs to be encoded twice:

```
&amp;nbsp;
```