# jquery .html shows html tags instead of applying html tags on the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.9

My code is

```
 printMsg : function(data) {
    $("#message").html(data.bodyText);
    ...
    }
```

here

```
data.bodyText   =    &lt;strong&gt; Test This Text  ;/strong&gt;
```

I am suppose to display data as  **Test This Text** & for that I did

```
 $("#message").html(data.bodyText);
```

This displayed the text correctly with jquery previous versions (1.9)

Now with jquery 1.10 it displays

```
<strong> Test This Text  </Strong>
```

Can you please tell me reason for this? & any solution if you have?

Comment: Have you tried to use `.text()` instead?

Comment: ya... .text() strips off html tags. For e.g. if I have data.bodyText   = </br>   &lt;strong&gt; Test This Text  ;/strong&gt;
... then it will ignore </br> tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to do something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/F9Kjt/)
in jquery 1.10.1 it seems work normally

**HTML**

```
<span id='message'></span>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {};
data.bodyText = "<strong>Test This Text;</strong>"; 
$("#message").html(data.bodyText);
```

Comment: instead of data.bodyText = "<strong>Test This Text;</strong>"; 
please check with  data.bodyText   =  "&lt;strong&gt; Test This Text  ;/strong&gt;" .... you will see the issue

Comment: ok, now i get it, u can do something like http://jsfiddle.net/F9Kjt/2/ where u replace the text.. take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784560/how-to-replace-lt-with-and-gt-with-using-jquery

Comment: This won't cover everything...check out this  http://jsfiddle.net/uDjES/ ... this should display **check3** in bold...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uDjES/1/ i just add a while, maybe u'll need just to add the ';' in that indexOf and reaplaces

Comment: yup... that works as expected. Any reason why this happened? I mean this used to work right with only .html before...

Comment: It happens *when you use single quotes* inside your tags instead of proper double quotes. e.g if your HTML content is `<p style='width:123px;'>Text</p>` it will force to display the html as text, using `<p style="width:123px;">Text</p>` will be set as HTML.