# jQuery append not rendering HTML escaped code

Tags: jquery

I'm using this jQuery command:

```
 $('.body-container').append(bodyPart.content).html();
```

to append HTML content into my body. If "bodyPart.content" is something like:

`<strong>Bold</strong>`

It works nicely, and show me on my browser:

**Bold**

But if it's:

`&lt;strong&gt; Bold &lt;/strong&gt;`

it shows me on the browser:

```
<strong> Bold </strong>
```

What to do here to jQuery understand escaped HTML code?

Comment: Try this (a little hack) http://stackoverflow.com/a/19381852/3639582

Comment: @ShaunakD Coincidentally enough, I just found the same method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities) and used it in my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `&lt;` and `&gt;` with the proper characters using replace like so:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var inp = $("input").val().replace(/&lt;/gi,"<").replace(/&gt;/gi,">");
    $('.body-container').append(inp).html();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/w7edc0cv/

---

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715801/javascript-decoding-html-entities), I think I may have managed to solve your issue (hopefully):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $('.body-container').append($('<div/>').html($("input").val()).text());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/w7edc0cv/3/

Comment: I appreciate your help, but you think this is the best solution? Because if it's, I will for the first time think that jQuery is missing something here.

Comment: I considered mentioning in my answer that this is kind of cheating, because it is. jQuery has a `$.parseHTML` method, but it only converts the characters to their text equivalents-- exactly what your previous code does. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/w7edc0cv/1/) for an example of this function. I don't even begin to pretend to know everything about jQuery, but it does appear that the function that you need is nonexistent.

Comment: On second thought, I may have managed to solve your issue. See my edited answer above.

Comment: Yes... Looks like this is nonexistent. I'll accept your answer in few time if doesn't appear anything 'official' for this question... I prefer the first solution you gave-me because the second one, if the HTML code isn't escaped, it will mess things up.

Comment: @user3810691 Refer to my updated answer for a working demo that does not use `replace`.

Comment: Yes, look the jsfiddle of the updated answer and try to append non escaped value. Something like `<strong>Bold</strong>`... and you will see that doesn't work... This is why I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry for my presumptuousness. My testing didn't take into account varied tags, and so while my test of `&lt;strong&gt; Bold </strong>` rendered properly, it wouldn't have had I used unescaped values for both tags. I didn't realize that until you pointed it out just now.